# Using a Java OutputFormat to emit Scala Tuples

Tags: java, scala, arangodb, apache-flink

I am trying to write a custom `OutputFormat` for ArangoDB.  I've used `CassandraOutputFormat.java` as inspiration, swapping out the relevant drivers and calls etc.  I wrote this in Java as I could not find a Scala example of an `OutputFormat`. The class therefore is defined by:

```
public class ArangoOutputFormat<OUT extends Tuple> extends RichOutputFormat<OUT>
```

Now, my Flink program where I want to write to ArangoDB is written in Scala. The dataset `test` is `DataSet[Tuple2[Long, Long]]`.  The call to write to ArangoDB looks like:

```
test.output(
  new ArangoOutputFormat[(Long, Long)]()
);
```

However when compiling I get the following error:

> Error:(47, 11) type arguments [(Long, Long)] do not conform to class ArangoOutputFormat's type parameter bounds [OUT <:
>   org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple]
>   new ArangoOutputFormat(Long, Long)

I'm generally a little confused on the type system when using both Scala and Java classes, can anyone explain what is happening here?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArangoOutputFormat is typed to Flink's Java Tuples (`org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple`) whereas your Scala program uses Scala's Tuples. Flink's Java tuples are not compatible with Scala's tuples. You need to explicitly create Java Tuples for instance in a Mapper before the sink.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i'm struggling to find a method to convert a scala.Tuple to a org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple, do you know of a nice way to do this?

Comment: How about converting `val st: (Int, String, Double) = (1, "a", 3.0)` to `val jt: Tuple3[Int, String, Double] = new Tuple3(st._1, st._2, st._3)`?

Comment: Thanks, using 
    test.map(x =>
      new org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2(x._1, x._2)
    ).output(
      new ArangoOutputFormat()
    );
worked perfectly